# Enable Azure PaaS Diagnostics sdk 2.8

Tags: azure, diagnostics

Trying to enable paas diagnostics on worker role in azure
Here is what I have tried:
 1. In VS2015, rightclick the role and enable diagnostics. Result: Timeout after   1 minute. Tried it several times.
 2. Enable with powershell:

```
$storage_name = "mystorageaccount"
$key = "typedstoragekeyhere"
$publicconfigpath = "C:\Temp\diagnostics.wadcfgx"
$servicename = "cloudservicename"
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $publicconfigpath -ServiceName $servicename -Slot Production
```

Result: Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : BadRequest: The extension public configuration... ...is invalid against schema 

followed by

and at the bottom: 
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Extensions.SetAzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionCommand

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating a worker role Visual Studio automatically enables Diagnostics 1.0 as part of the solution, so you need to disable it first. Right click on the Worker role > Properties > Configuration, then uncheck Enable Diagnostics
   [image]
2. Download the public configuration file schema definition by executing the following PowerShell command:

   (Get-AzureServiceAvailableExtension -ExtensionName 'PaaSDiagnostics' -ProviderNamespace 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics').PublicConfigurationSchema | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath 'WadConfig.xsd'
3. Add an XML file to your WorkerRole project and make your own Diagnostic configuration, then associate the WadConfig.xsd we get in step 2 with the xml file.
   [image]
4. Run the command below:

   ```
   $storage_name = "storageName"
   $key = "StorageAccountKey"
   $config_path="the xml path created in step 3"
   $service_name="serviceName"
   $storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key
   Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $config_path -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Staging -Role WorkerRole1
   ```

Now the PaaS Diagnostics Extension is enabled for your worker role. See more details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/).